# Distinguishing between people who have likes to posts and those who have dislikes

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

I want to distinguish between people who have likes to posts and those who have dislikes. I want to find a way to improve my code without thinking it is efficient.

```
<% if current_user.voted_up_on? @post %>
  <%= link_to "LIKE #{@post.get_upvotes.size}", like_post_path(@post), method: :post, class: "btn btn-outline-primary" %>
  <%= link_to "DISLIKE #{@post.get_downvotes.size}", dislike_post_path(@post), method: :post, class: "btn btn-outline-dark" %>
<% elsif current_user.voted_down_on? @post %>
  <%= link_to "LIKE #{@post.get_upvotes.size}", like_post_path(@post), method: :post, class: "btn btn-outline-dark" %>
  <%= link_to "DISLIKE #{@post.get_downvotes.size}", dislike_post_path(@post), method: :post, class: "btn btn-outline-danger" %>
<% else %>
  <%= link_to "LIKE #{@post.get_upvotes.size}", like_post_path(@post), method: :post, class: "btn btn-outline-dark" %>
  <%= link_to "DISLIKE #{@post.get_downvotes.size}", dislike_post_path(@post), method: :post, class: "btn btn-outline-dark" %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cam think of a couple of options. You could simplify this into something like:

```
<% if current_user.voted_up_on? @post %>
  <%= link_to "LIKE #{@post.get_upvotes.size}", like_post_path(@post), 
<% else %>
  <%= link_to "LIKE #{@post.get_upvotes.size}", like_post_path(@post), method: :post, class: "btn btn-outline-dark" %>
<% end %>

<% if current_user.voted_down_on? @post %>
  <%= link_to "DISLIKE #{@post.get_downvotes.size}", dislike_post_path(@post), method: :post, class: "btn btn-outline-danger" %>
<% else %>
  <%= link_to "DISLIKE #{@post.get_downvotes.size}", dislike_post_path(@post), method: :post, class: "btn btn-outline-dark" %>
<% end %>
```

However, I usually prefer something like

```
<% like_class    = current_user.voted_up_on?(@post)   ? 'btn-outline-primary' : 'btn-outline-dark' %>
<% dislike_class = current_user.voted_down_on?(@post) ? 'btn-outline-danger'  : 'btn-outline-dark' %>

<%= link_to "LIKE #{@post.get_upvotes.size}", like_post_path(@post), method: :post, class:like_class %>
<%= link_to "DISLIKE #{@post.get_downvotes.size}", dislike_post_path(@post), method: :post, class: dislike_class %>
```

A few things:

1. I would probably put this into a helper method.
2. Usually you would hide or at least disable the like button if the post has already been liked.
3. You haven't shown your model's code but you need to be careful that you don't query the database twice, once for `voted_up_on?` and once for `voted_down_on?`. Since they are mutually exclusive you may want to have a single method that return the state (up, down or none) and use a case statement.

Answer (score 0):

As  you can easily identify from your code that `link_to` code for `Like` and `Dislike`  are same for all conditions only the `class` value is changed
so you can use below code it looks more clean:

```
<% like_class = current_user.voted_up_on? @post ? 'btn-outline-primary' : 'btn-outline-dark' %>
<% dislike_class = current_user.voted_down_on? @post ? 'btn-outline-danger' : 'btn-outline-dark' %>
<%= link_to "LIKE #{@post.get_upvotes.size}", like_post_path(@post), method: :post, class: "btn #{like_class}" %>
<%= link_to "DISLIKE #{@post.get_downvotes.size}", dislike_post_path(@post), method: :post, class: "btn #{dislike_class}" %>
```